# What does `I/System.out: -1` mean in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have created programmatically a `RelativeLayout` which contains a `textView`. I'm trying to get the id of the `textView` using this code:

```
System.out.println(textView.getId());
```

When i try to see the result it prints out -1? What does it mean?
Thanks!

Comment: it means that you didn't assign an `id` to the `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `I/System.out: -1` because your `TextView` view **not** your `RelativeLayout` as Blackbelt commented, does not have an `id`.

To get the real id:

1. Assign in an id first
2. and then use `textView.getId()`.